# How to upload a video to YouTube using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, video, youtube

I want to upload a video to YouTube using Google Apps Script. Here is my code, including what I've tried and what the errors are.

Code.gs

```
/**
 * @see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert
 * @param { String } sourceUrl url location of the source video file in google drive
 * @returns { Video }
 */
const uploadVideo2youtube = sourceId => {
  const sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById( sourceId, ).getBlob();
  const videoResource = {
    snippet: {
      title: 'Summer vacation in California',
      description: 'Had a great time surfing in Santa Cruz',
      tags: [ 'surfing', 'Santa Cruz', ],
      categoryId: '22',
    },
  };
  // const status = { privacyStatus: 'Private', };
  const status = { privacyStatus: 'private', };

  // here are all my attempts and the errors with each one...
  // const newVideo = YouTube.Videos.insert( videoResource, status, sourceFile, ); // GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.insert failed with error: '{privacyStatus=private}' (line 229, file "Code")
  // const newVideo = YouTube.Videos.insert( videoResource, sourceFile, ); // GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.insert failed with error: Blob (line 230, file "Code")
  const newVideo = YouTube.Videos.insert( videoResource, [ status ], sourceFile, ); // GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.insert failed with error: '{privacyStatus=private}' (line 231, file "Code")

  Logger.log('(line 213) newVideo:\n%s', JSON.stringify( newVideo ),);
}
const upload2youtube_test = () => upload2youtube( <fileId>, )
```

As you can see from the code, I have made several attempts at the `YouTube.Videos.insert()` method. But each attempt throws an error. Yes, I have enabled the YouTube Data API v3 resource under my resources tab and authorized the script to run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please include `status` in `videoResource`.
- The 2nd argument of `YouTube.Videos.insert(resource, part, mediaData)` is `part`. In this case, it's `"snippet,status"`.

#### Modified script:

```
const sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceId).getBlob();
const videoResource = {
  snippet: {
    title: 'Summer vacation in California',
    description: 'Had a great time surfing in Santa Cruz',
    tags: [ 'surfing', 'Santa Cruz', ],
    categoryId: '22',
  },
  status: {privacyStatus: 'private'}  // Added
};
const newVideo = YouTube.Videos.insert( videoResource, "snippet,status", sourceFile);  // Modified
```

#### Note:

- In this case, it is required to enable YouTube Data API v3 at Advanced Google services. Please be careful this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

#### References:

- [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)
- [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)